# gmock: Testing two float vectors

Tags: googletest, googlemock

I am trying to write a test for a vector.
For STL containers, I tried:

```
EXPECT_THAT(float_vec1, ElementsAreArray(float_vec2));
```

However I need to insert a margin.

Is there an `ElementsAreArray` equivalent of `FloatNear(a_float, max_abs_error)`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I've used the `Pointwise` container matcher, which you can give a matcher and an expected container (any STL container and is compatible with non-dynamically allocated c-style arrays).

```
EXPECT_THAT(float_vec1, Pointwise(matcher, float_vec2))
```

For the **matcher** You can use `FloatEq()` which uses ULP-based float comparisons.

```
EXPECT_THAT(float_vec1, Pointwise(FloatEq(), float_vec2))
```

However, I've found it is easier to use `FloatNear(float max_abs_error)` just to define my own floating point error like you want.

```
float ferr = 1e-5;
EXPECT_THAT(float_vec1,
            Pointwise(FloatNear(ferr), float_vec2));
```

Comment: That would work, but unlike `Eq`, `FloatEq` does not have a default constructor, so unfortunately it looks like it cannot be used with `Pointwise`.

Comment: Actually it works as demonstrated in the last example above, i.e. `Pointwise(FloatNear(1e-5), float_vec2)` works fine for me.